# Add a column to Apache Beam PCollection in Golang

Tags: go, beam

I'm trying to add string field (`date`) to a PCollection on a Beam pipeline written in Go. The value of this field will ultimately be determined by a parameter passed to my pipeline, although for now I'm hard-coding in a date for testing purposes.

Here is the relevant code:

```
type AddStringDoFn struct {
    StringToAdd string
}

func (d *AddStringDoFn) ProcessElement(x beam.X, st string) (string, beam.X) {
    return st, x
}
```

Then, in the pipeline, here is how I call the function (hardcoding a date for testing purposes):

```
col_with_dates := beam.ParDo(scope, &AddStringDoFn{StringToAdd: "2023-01-01"}, col)
```

Where `col` is the input PCollection.

When I run this code, I get an error:

```
panic:  inserting ParDo in scope root
        creating new DoFn in scope root
        binding fn reflect.methodValueCall
        binding params [{Value typex.X} {Value string}] to input [main.PrivateModel]
too few inputs: forgot an input or to annotate options?
```

What parameters am I missing here? Or is my DoFn malfomred?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below

```
type AddStringDoFn struct {
    StringToAdd string
}

func (d *AddStringDoFn) ProcessElement(x beam.X) (string, beam.X) {
    return d.StringToAdd, x
}
```

Then call the function

```
col_with_dates := beam.ParDo(scope, &AddStringDoFn{StringToAdd: "2023-01-01"}, col, beam.TypeDefinition{Var: beam.XType, T: reflect.TypeOf("")})
```